# Cannot bake a normal map (high-poly sculpt to low-poly model)

Tags: texturing, sculpting, normals, texture-baking, normal-map

So this seems to be a common issue but I've followed the troubleshooting in other posts here and can't figure out what my issue is.

- I have a high-poly sculpt and a low-poly version, both with scale/rot/loc applied.
- The high-poly version is a tiny bit bigger.
- Low-poly is UV wrapped
- I created an image for the normal map with 32 bit float checked
- Added the generated blank map to the texture but not connected (to avoid the circular dependency error)
- Both objects are auto-smoothed
- I select the high-poly, then low-poly object
- 'Selected to active' is checked
- Extrusion set to 0.1m
  This is my result
  [image: normal map]
  [image: low-poly with the messed up UVs]

This is the high-poly mesh:
[image: Add wear and damage to the edges]

I've tried changing the extrusion and max ray distance values and the results only get worse. I've also tried a cage but that normal map was worse too. I've followed numerous youtube tutorials so I have no idea at this point. The UV map was done using smart project so could that be the issue? I feel like it should be fine because some of the tutorials used that method too. There's no overlap in my UVs

[image]

Comment: hello, have you checked the normal orientation? if this is still not the problem please share your file

Comment: Like moonboots says, first, check the normals for both high and low are pointing the right direction, using "face orientation" in overlays dropdown.  Second, you probably want to increase ray extrusion, but not max ray: leave it at 0, which isn't 0 at all, but actually means infinite.  An alternative to ray extrusion is a temporary displace modifier on the low poly, which is easier to visualize: you want the low poly to completely enclose the high poly, not vice versa, and ray extrusion (or temporary displacement) is the way to achieve that.  Finally, you don't want autosmooth on the low.

Comment: There were a couple faces outside the camera with backwards normals but I assume that shouldn't affect the rest of the mesh? I'll add that screenshot to the post. I tried zipping the file but it's still too large for blend-exchange.com even with only the two meshes :/

Comment: please upload your file on another platform like workupload